# Element appended in a directive exists but not visible

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use SVG inside an angular directive which uses an image as background and then draws on top of it.

The problem I have is the elements drawn are created and apparently appended, but they are not displayed. I'm probably using the append function incorrectly, but I don´t know why.

This is my directive

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.directive("myDir",function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            var svg = angular.element('<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="50"/>');
            iElement.append(svg);

        },
        template:'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200"><image x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" xlink:href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"/></svg>'


    }
});
```

and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/tqdxyzqf/) with it.

Many thanks.

Comment: looks like you need to compile element before injecting `iElement.append($compile(svg)(scope));`

Comment: I read about that, but it doesn´t seem to make any difference anyway

Comment: You're creating a circle element in the html namespace rather than the SVG namespace. You'd have to debug the angularjs code to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I still don´t know why the original code does not work, but I found a way to make it work, at least until someone comes with an explanation regarding the original code.

This is what I used instead of `var svg = angular.element('<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="50"/>');`

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("cx",10);
circle.setAttribute("cy",10);
circle.setAttribute("r",10);
```

And then append it as before with `iElement.append(circle);`

Comment: Check this answer for jquery.append not working with svg element http://goo.gl/rl9yz